# Fourier transform of functions mapping manifolds, is there a definition?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lie-groups, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, smooth-manifolds

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$I have a problem which boils down to the analysis of functions of the form
$$
f : \mathbb{R} \to \SO(3)^n
$$
Since $\SO(3)$ is a compact group so is $\SO(3)^n$.
Now if instead of having such a mapping I'd had something from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ I would've applied the Fourier transform componentwise (which I think is a valid definition of Fourier transform for such functions, please correct me if I am wrong).

However I cannot do the same thing in the case I am given because $\SO(3)$ is not even a vector space in the first place. I wonder if there's any definition of Fourier Transform that can be applied to my case.

Is there a definition I could use? or something someone came up with that might be useful in this case?

I know for functions $f: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is a Riemannian manifold there's a definition of Fourier transform, relying on the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Can this be generalized if the target space is another manifold?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe functions "targeting" manifolds would be a better choice of words.

Comment: I guess but because lie groups have a bit of more structure I thought it was more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Hopefully is clearer now.

Comment: Could you spell out *why* you would apply a Fourier transform, i.e., what properties you want it to satisfy?

Comment: Cause I have a time series data of rotations expressed as matrices/quaternions or equivalent. Because of that target space I abstracted the question in the one I've asked. Just wondering if someone has thought about it really.

Comment: The problem is that askng for a Fourier transform of an $\operatorname{SO}(3)^n$-valued function is quite similar to asking "I have some data; should I use the Fourier transform, the Laplace transform, or the Riesz transform?"  Without context, there's no way to give an appropriate answer.  Usually the Fourier transform is meant to exploit symmetries in the *domain*, so it's less clear to me what to do with symmetries on the *target*.

Comment: Well, $SO(3)$ is not a vector space, but it embeds into $\mathbb{R}^9$ as $3\times 3$ matrices. You can just think of you functions as taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{9n}$, ignoring that the actual range is smaller. It is not clear without further context why this is this inadequate.

Comment: @Kostya_I I thought of that but I wonder if there's something like Banach algebra style. With that I mean you can derive the fourier transform in $L^1$ by finding the set of all homomorphism $\left\{ \phi \right\}$. Namely you go with $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ a bit of manipulations and you end up with the fourier transform. Don't know if this make  sense but this is what I was going for. Homomrphism for groups are well defined, I thought maybe there's something there?

Comment: Another option for the case where $f$ is differentiable is to form the derivative of $f$ as a map $f':\mathbb{R}\to so_3^n$ to the lie algebra of $SO(3)^n$, and as lie algebras are vector spaces you can try to compute the Fourier transform of $f'$